# clean install of LEMP but not able to access sites

Tags: php, nginx, server, block

So my problem is that I have 2 sites set up both using wordpress yet to be configured. I try and put  an info.php in each to show php running but get 404 not found. The problem really lies in not knowing whether my nginx server blocks are even working. I did a clean install of everything and even wiped out nginx and php-fpm because i tried using an nginx server block generator. I can get php info to show fine when i visit the server at its ip address. Id reinstalled nginx and php successfully but only get the main nginx page when i try to go to either site not the wordpress config wizzard. Yourhelpwould be greatly appreciated. Attached are my nginx.config, each server block, and a few commands run.

nginx -t says nginx config files are ok

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

PHP-FPM and nginx are running fine
PHP-FPM Status:

```
● php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-01 21:31:35 UTC; 1 weeks 2 days ago
 Main PID: 66980 (php-fpm)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 6, Requests: 1137, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 11511)
   Memory: 44.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/php-fpm.service
           ├─66980 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─66981 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─66982 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─66983 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─66984 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─66985 php-fpm: pool www
           └─77605 php-fpm: pool www

Jul 01 21:31:35  systemd[1]: Stopped The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
Jul 01 21:31:35  systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
Jul 01 21:31:35  systemd[1]: Started The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
```

nginx status:

```
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-01 21:31:29 UTC; 1 weeks 2 days ago
  Process: 66971 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 66967 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 66965 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 66972 (nginx)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 11511)
   Memory: 6.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─66972 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
           ├─66973 nginx: worker process
           └─66974 nginx: worker process

Jul 01 21:31:29 systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Jul 01 21:31:29 nginx[66967]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Jul 01 21:31:29 nginx[66967]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Jul 01 21:31:29 systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

My firewall is running and configured to listen on ports 80 and 443 http and https:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth1
  sources: 
  services: http https other services edited for privacy
  ports: edited for privacy
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

netstat -tlnp shows nginx listening on both ports 80 and 443

Last but not least here are the config files for each server block: server names rewritten for privacy purposes:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example1.com www.example1.com;

#    rewrite ^ https://example1.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

#    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem;
#    ssl_stapling on;

    server_name example1.com;

    root /var/www/example1/public_html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

server block 2

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.co www.example.co;

#    rewrite ^ https://example.co$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

#    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/fullchain.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem;
#    ssl_stapling on;

    server_name example.co;

    root /var/www/example/public_html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Both server block files are located in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/ folder.

Any suggestions to help me get this working would be amazing and greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you config `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to have `nginx` user and group instead of `apache2`? also you must config it to listen on `/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock` with `nginx` listen user and group

Comment: What does any of this have to do with LEMP? Did you mean LAMPP?

Comment: No LEMP and LAMP are 2 different animals. LEMP is Linux, Enginx Mysql, PHP Where as LAMP has apache instead of Nginx

Comment: @mjrezaee I had configured php-fpm/www.conf to use nginx as user and group. As for configuring it to use that sock file the one on my system is www.sock instead of php-fpm sock

Comment: For what it’s worth I’d forgotten to switch users in www.conf but my problem still remains the same. Any thoughts on this?